# How to add Validation for multiple checkboxes in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

So I've just got a form set up with a list checkboxes of states so that you can select multiple states, however I'm not quite sure how to put the validation on the *collection* of checkboxes rather than each individual one.

Right now, I have:

**my-view.html**

```
    <div repeat.for="territory of availableTerritories" class="form-row">
        <input type="checkbox" value.bind="territory" checked.bind="region.territories & validate">
        <label>${territory}</label>
    </div>

    <ul if.bind="validationController.errors">
        <li repeat.for="error of validationController.errors">
            ${error.message}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="button cancel" click.trigger="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="button ok" click.trigger="saveRegion()">Save Territories</button>
```

**my-viewmodel.js**

```
availableTerritories = [
'US-AL',
'US-AK',
...
]

region = {
    territories: []
}

constructor(validationController) {
    ValidationRules
        .ensure(region=>region.territories)
            .required()
            .minItems(1)
            .on(this.region);
}
```

However, when I test this out with an empty input, I get a ValidationError for *every* checkbox rather than just the collection of them.

**My ValidationError message**

> - Territories must contain at least 1 item.
> - Territories must contain at least 1 item.
> - Territories must contain at least 1 item.
> - ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up adding a hidden input to the form and doing the validation on that, instead of the checkboxes themselves:

**my-view.html**

```
<div repeat.for="territory of availableTerritories" class="form-row">
    <input type="checkbox" value.bind="territory" checked.bind="region.territories">    // No validation here
    <label>${territory}</label>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value.bind="region.territories & validate">    //Added validation here instead

<ul if.bind="validationController.errors">
    <li repeat.for="error of validationController.errors">
        ${error.message}
    </li>
</ul>
<button class="button cancel" click.trigger="cancel()">Cancel</button>
<button class="button ok" click.trigger="saveRegion()">Save Territories</button>
```

Comment: So I'm not sure if the hidden input is the best way to do this, or if it is possible to do it directly through the checkboxes. I would welcome any possible better ways to go about it.